# c++ library to wasm with emscripten, how to debug "error: Async: promise callback"

Tags: c++, webassembly, emscripten

I'm trying to build a c++ library and a main.cpp with emscripten to wasm. The main.cpp contains several functions from the library. Most of the functions work except for one that stream data. When I run the main.html in the browser (Firefox / also tested Chrome and Safari) I get the following error:

```
printErr http://0.0.0.0:8080/main.html:109
callMain http://0.0.0.0:8080/main.js:8456
doRun http://0.0.0.0:8080/main.js:8480
run http://0.0.0.0:8080/main.js:8489
(Async: setTimeout handler)
run http://0.0.0.0:8080/main.js:8485
runCaller http://0.0.0.0:8080/main.js:8424
removeRunDependency http://0.0.0.0:8080/main.js:1262
receiveInstance http://0.0.0.0:8080/main.js:1365
receiveInstantiatedSource http://0.0.0.0:8080/main.js:1372
(Async: promise callback)
instantiateArrayBuffer http://0.0.0.0:8080/main.js:1377
instantiateAsync http://0.0.0.0:8080/main.js:1391
(Async: promise callback)
instantiateAsync http://0.0.0.0:8080/main.js:1388
(Async: promise callback)
instantiateAsync http://0.0.0.0:8080/main.js:1386
createWasm http://0.0.0.0:8080/main.js:1408
```

I have built the library with:

```
emcmake cmake 
emmake make
```

to libfoo.a libfoo2.a

To compile the main.cpp with the lib I'm runnign:

```
emcc main.cpp libfoo.a libfoo2.a -s WASM=1 -o main.html -s EXTRA_EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS='["ccall","cwrap"]' -s ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH=1 -s --shell-file shell_minimal.html
```

I'm using macOS and the latest emscripten (2.0.8).

Any ideas how to proceed with the debugging?

Comment: Would [this](https://scotch.io/courses/10-need-to-know-javascript-concepts/callbacks-promises-and-async) or [this](https://itnext.io/javascript-promises-vs-rxjs-observables-de5309583ca2) link about promises help you?

Comment: Thanks, that looks like a good start

Comment: have you worked with Ascynchronos calls before? Did you figure out what the problem is? Did you make `main.js` yourself because it seems like a rather large file? What do the calls look like?

Comment: No, I haven't worked with async calls before. I partially solved the issue by adding the flags '-s USE_PTHREADS=1 --std=c++11'. But I now have an error: 'memory access out of bounds' (caused by the c++ logger spdlog). I used the automatically generated main.js. Perhaps it's a good idea to use a custom js to narrow down the problem.